# Microsoft Teams navigate in a view and press a button (mute all)?

Tags: accessibility, microsoft-teams, screen-readers

How to click a button when the frame is highlighted after SHIFT+TAB **on mac**?

Is this not supported in the OSX app as part of accessibility/screen reader feature in MS Teams and description of how to [navigate in a view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-a-screen-reader-to-explore-and-navigate-microsoft-teams-47614fb0-a583-49f6-84da-6872223e74a0#bkmk_navigateinsideview_mac)?

I can't figure out i.e. how to click `Admit all` or `Mute all`.

FYI - I'm writing applescript to press the required keys sequences accordingly.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: FYI - the web client supports selecting the button, I have to use the desktop app though for other features.
[image]

Comment: You should try superuser.com as that is more likely to get an answer there.  I don't think this quite fits on SO as it isn't about software development.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie thanks, i thought it might as it might be more a generic navigation question how MS software works and also I'm coding applescript to press keys to navigate accordingly (since there is no functions/api/shortcuts) for this.

Comment: Wow, a huge accessibility issue for MS Teams. I tried this on a PC and had the same trouble. Left/right arrow while on "waiting in lobby" just expands/collapses that section. Up/down arrow moves me to each person waiting but I couldn't get to the "admit all" button. I even tried with NVDA and brought up the button list and "admit all" was not in the list. Ironically, MS was going to hire me as the a11y lead for MS Teams earlier this year then they decided they didn't need someone to help with that. Obviously they do.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft yeah with no problem, i added a screenshot to the OP. Steps to reproduce would be in calendar create a meeting and invite one user, you can use the join URL and open in different browsers/incognito to join 2 guests, then open the participants pane and try to navigate with the TAB button, it only cycles through the different sections, only the main menu buttons on the top can be triggered.

Comment: @Markus - We are able to select "Mute all" & "Admin all" using Web & Teams desktop client on window but there is no way to click on those buttons. I will check with engineering team and let you know.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft thanks, seems to be an issue with the mac desktop client, I cleared cache just in case but no success. If only shortcuts were available. =)

Comment: @Markus - Did you get any change to check in Web or Desktop Teams client?
Are you able to put focus on "Mute all" or "Admin all" using Tab key?

Is your issue related to only focus or button click shortcut key?

Comment: web works, desktop does not work where I tried using tab key, one can't focus on the button and thus neither click it in the OSX app.

Comment: I've just tried on Teams version 1.4.00.26376 on Windows 10, when I tabbed to the "Mute All" accordion, and I pressed the Applications Key (or Shift F10) a context menu appeared with the "Mute All" option that I could then access by keyboard. So, like the OP, I can't directly access the "Mute All" button when the accordion panel has focus, but I can access it by using the context menu.

Comment: @Markus - I have raised a internal bug for it and engineering team will look into it.

Comment: All actions on the tree are accessible via context menu and the context menu shortcut. From https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-do-i-open-the-context-menu-from-a-mac-keyboard
this is an equivalent of `menu` or shift+F10 on Windows.  **Note:** it is the position of the pointer and not that of the cursor that determines where the contextual menu pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the desktop version of Teams (1.4.00.26376) on Windows 10; similarly to the OP I also found I couldn't access the 'Mute All' button when focus was on the 'Attendees/In this meeting' accordion panel. But, I could access the 'Mute All' button when I used the Applications Key (or Shift F10) a context menu appeared with the 'Mute All' option and I could access it with the keyboard.

[image: Demonstration of context menu for Mute All in Teams Meeting window]

Comment: Sorry George but the question/issue is with the mac/osx desktop app, not windows. I also tried the option key, any key for that matter. I put more emphasis in the post on this being a mac issue. Thanks for checking George!

Comment: No worries, sorry that I didn't pick up on that in my answer.

Comment: Great that it works for Windows at least, which is of course a larger use base out there :) takes  more effort for Mac ports to be matched.